# Retrieving a CI variable from Gitlab project and use it within Dockerfile

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, environment-variables

I have a CI variable that I would like to use within my docker file. I have tried to include it such as

```
ENV TESTING_UNIT=$TESTING_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that you need to specify to Dockerfile that it expects an argument variable

With the following approach it will be available in the container

Change:

```
ENV TESTING_UNIT=$TESTING_ID
```

To:

```
ARG TESTING_UNIT_ARG
ENV TESTING_UNIT=$TESTING_UNIT_ARG
```

and build the image: 
 `docker build --build-arg TESTING_UNIT_ARG=$TESTING_ID`

Comment: Can I use the TESTING_UNIT as a value in the container? How would I be able to use it within the container?

Comment: The TESTING_UNIT variable will be available only within your Dockerfile, as your question implies.
If you want to have the variable available in your docker container use docker run  -e TESTING_UNIT=$TESTING_ID

Comment: I places build the image `docker build --build-arg TESTING_UNIT=$TESTING_ID` and within my docker file I have 
`ARG TESTING_UNITL`

`ENV TESTING_UNIT=${TESTING_UNIT}` but it shows as an empty string.

Comment: @PaulBlart Sorry for the late response, does the updated answer provide the expected response?